# Add and edit data into specific table refer to table name not columns

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have one sheet that has 4 tables and I’m using userform to input data into each table but I need to know how to edit data in specific tables without referring to columns A or b …… I want to refer the table name and header name of the table

this example to add data into the tables

```
Dim cellrange As String
Dim rowno As Integer

Dim AddFood As ListObject
Dim AddBev As ListObject
Dim AddOther As ListObject

Set AddFood = Data.ListObjects("T_Food")
Set AddBev = Data.ListObjects("T_Beverage")
Set AddOther = Data.ListObjects("T_Other")
Dim AddedRow As ListRow

If txtCode.Text = "" Or comDepartment.Text = "" Or txtItemName.Text = "" Or comUnit.Text = "" _
    Or txtPrice.Text = "" Or TxtSalePrice.Text = "" Then
      Beep
   MsgBox " Please Enter Data "
Exit Sub
```

End If

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  '''''''''''''''''''''''                                                             

 Set Da = Data 
 Set ww = Application.WorksheetFunction
With Da
     If Me.comDepartment = "Food" Then
  cname = Me.txtItemName.Text
  fc = ww.CountIf(Data.Range("T_Food[[Item Name]]"), cname)
   If fc >= 1 Then
   amedia = MsgBox("  This name already exists  ", vbCritical, "Inventory Program")
 Exit Sub
```

End If

```
Set AddedRow = AddFood.ListRows.Add()
  With AddedRow
       AddedRow.Range(1) = Me.txtCode.Text    'Code
       AddedRow.Range(2) = Me.txtItemName.Text  'name
       AddedRow.Range(3) = Me.txtCode.Text
       AddedRow.Range(4) = Me.comUnit.Text         'Unit
       AddedRow.Range(5) = Me.txtPrice.Text        'CostPrice
       AddedRow.Range(6) = Me.TxtSalePrice.Text
       AddedRow.Range(8) = Me.comDepartment.Text  'Department
```

Comment: What is `Da` from the last part of the code? Anyhow, you do not use it at all...

Answer (score 0):

Any cell (`Range`) from any Excel row (even for a `ListRow`) has `Row` property, which is 1 and `Column` property, which should be incremented to obtain the following one. So, please try understanding the next code and apply its meaning:

```
Dim Data As Worksheet, addFood As ListObject, AddedRow As listRow, strExisting As String
  
  Set Data = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  Set addFood = Data.ListObjects("T_Food")
  
  Set AddedRow = addFood.ListRows.Add()
  With AddedRow
        If Application.CountIf(addFood.DataBodyRange.Columns(1),  Me.txtCode.Text) = 0 Then
            .Range(1, 1) = Me.txtCode.Text
        Else
            strExisting = strExisting & vbCrLf & Me.txtCode.Text
        End If
        If Application.CountIf(addFood.DataBodyRange.Columns(2), Me.txtItemName.Text) = 0 Then
            .Range(1, 2) = Me.txtItemName.Text
        Else
            strExisting = strExisting & vbCrLf & Me.txtItemName.Text
        End If
  End With
  If strExisting <> "" Then MsgBox "The next values already exist in their respective columns:" & vbCrLf & strExisting
```

**Edited**:

Please, try understanding/using the next way for changing any value from the table `DataBodyRange`. Instead of extracting the column number using its Header, you can use directly that number, if more convenient:

```
Sub ChangingTableRowsElements()
   Dim Data As Worksheet, addFood As ListObject, findCode As Range
   Dim srcCode As String, changeElem As String, arrCols, ColToBeChanged As String, col
   
   srcCode = Me.txtCode.Text 'the code to be searched for changing
   changeElem = "ToBeChanged" 'the new string value to be placed instead existing
   ColToBeChanged = "Price" 'you should place here A REAL COLUMN HEADER
   
   Set Data = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
   Set addFood = Data.ListObjects("T_Food")
   arrCols = addFood.HeaderRowRange.Value 'you may skip this code line if you want supplying the column to be changed number.
   
   Set findCode = addFood.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Find(what:=srcCode, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) 'find the code to be changed cell
   If Not findCode Is Nothing Then   'the code could be found in the table first column
      col = Application.match(ColToBeChanged, arrCols, 0) 'you may skip this and make col  = 5, meaning the fifth column
      If Not IsError(col) Then
           findCode.Offset(, col - 1).Value = changeElem
      Else
           MsgBox ColToBeChanged & " could not be found between the table headers...": Exit Sub
      End If
   Else
       MsgBox srcCode & " could not be found between the codes in the table first column..."
   End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: I tried it still add row didn't edit

Comment: @Mohamed Amin What do you mean  by  "didn't edit "? Didn't it writhe in the first two column of the newly inserted row the values of the respective text boxes? Are you sure that there are values/texts in the respective ones?

Comment: I mean that code can be added row but I need it to edit some of data bu userfrom

Comment: @Mohamed Amin I asked you above: **What do you mean by editing**? When you add a row, **of course**. it is empty. **Doesn't the text from the used text boxes (`txtCode` and `txtItemName`) appear in the first two cells/columns of the newly inserted row**? If yes, what else do you want doing? To return (by code) what value is in the first/second such a cell? If not, what else do you mean by editing?

Comment: @Mohamed Amin Do you want preliminarily checking **if the respective string to be added in the respective column already exists** and add it only **if not**?

Comment: @Mohamed Amin I could see that you edited your question after I posted my answer. I am not sure that I understood what you really want doing, but I adapted my code answer to preliminarily check if the respective string to be written in the newly inserted row already exists on that respective column. Please, test it and send some feedback. I am not sure that I am able to get you...

Comment: I need to code the same as that code after I added the row If want to modify the data (Item name, Price, Cost...) I can

Comment: @Mohamed Amin You can do it, but you always must clearly explain what you need in your question... It is difficult to work on assumptions. Now, if you need to change any of the enumerated column elements **of the last row** it is easy, you should proceed as in the code example. I (only) suppose that you need to change any of existing columns elements **based on the first column Code**. I do not like working only by assumptions, so can you confirm that this is what you want doing?

Comment: @Mohamed Amin Since, you do not answer the clarification question, I will edit the above code and add a code version supposing that my above assumption is correct. Anyhow, you can learn from it and use the solution as you need. Besides that, I would like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question, **as it has been formulated**, in a convenient way, we tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the supplied solution works...